# Standard Test for Multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

Is there a more-or-less standard statistical test out there for checking whether a multivariate data set is being drawn from a multivariate Gaussian distribution?

I suppose I could calculate the empirical mean vector and covariance matrix and then use them to calculate the likelihood, but is there a better way?

Many thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. You may also be interested in reading [is-normality-testing-essentially-useless?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/)

Comment: See https://doi.org/10.1007/s11749-020-00740-0 for a recent review of methodologies.