# Is this a legitimate method to test for multivariate normality?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, multivariate-normal-distribution

I've been digging deep for methods to test multivariate normality (MVN) of data of about 10-12 dimensions (usual methods like the Shapiro-Wilk don't seem to have enough power for this). I recently came upon [this publication](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgr4k1r3phg3arc/A%20characterization%20of%20multivariate%20normality%20through%20univariate%20projections.pdf?dl=0)$^\dagger$, which in **Remark 3** on the final page suggests that for a datapoint $X_k$ of MVN  data $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$ the projections of all other $X_i$ datapoints on $X_k$ (given by $X_k^TX_i$ for $X_i$) are guaranteed to be normally distributed. Do I interpret this correctly? If I do can I use this to develop a test for multivariate normality based on this argument?

---

$\dagger$ link dead

Comment: See [How to do normality test for high dimension data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519524/how-to-do-normality-test-for-high-dimension-data), [Standard Gaussianity test for high dimensional data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238154/standard-gaussianity-test-for-high-dimensional-data), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79270/standard-test-for-multivariate-gaussian